# Prefab game object isn't being Destroyed

Tags: unity-game-engine

I tried two ways of destroying my prefab game objects and neither seems to work.  I want the object to be Instantiated when the Spawn method is called, then Destroy after the timeOfTravel variable's float value has passed. First I tried in the same method that Instantiates the object with the code below:

```
void Spawn () {

    Vector2 spawn = new Vector2 (gameObject.transform.position.x, gameObject.transform.position.y);
    GameObject ballInstance = Instantiate (ball, spawn, Quaternion.identity, parent);
    Destroy (ballInstance.gameObject, ballInstance.GetComponent<Ball>().timeOfTravel);

}
```

but the game object is never destroyed, it just sits in the hierarchy.
So I tried running this simple line in a script attached to the prefab but it also did not remove the object from the hierarchy:

```
void Start () {

    Destroy (gameObject, timeOfTravel);

}
```

The prefabs being Instantiated are Image objects on a UI Canvas if that makes a difference, but I can't figure out why they aren't being destroyed.  I think I may not be referencing the object instance correctly?

Comment: Your first case could potentially be an issue, but your second case looks fine to me. If you're using Visual Studio, you could set a break point in your second example, then Attach to Unity to see what's happening with those values. In the first example though, when you instantiate an object, it hasn't been fully set up straight away. A lot of the initialisation occurs just before the next frame update. So you might be trying to destroy an object that isn't fully formed yet. it might be your .gameObject reference to itself. The components (Ball) might not be set yet either.

Comment: Your code looks logically correct.Perhaps make your Gameobject a child of an empty object, then destroying that object.

Comment: Any update on this one? I'm encountering the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to destroy the gameobject instantly using "Destroy(this.gameobject);"? Maybe something is wrong with your "timeoftravel" function.

Comment: I tried this.gameObject as well and it did not work.  timeOfTravel is just a float, not a function.  It's making use of the 2 argument Destroy constructor that takes in a delay time as a float

Comment: Your logic seems fine. One thing i do not know is wheter if assigning gameobject to a parent on instantiating changes some logic. I would try to remove "parent" from here GameObject ballInstance = Instantiate (ball, spawn, Quaternion.identity, parent);, then try if it works. If not i have no idea why this is not working...

Comment: It needs to be parented to the Canvas for the Image object to appear